# input does not follow line-height property

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am currently having an issue with the `line-height` property. At present, I am using this in order to make the text appear **below** the middle (~ 2/3 of the way down the div).

```css
.squ {
  height: 30vw;
  width: 40vw;
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.jbcol3 {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}
.squ input,
.squ a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="jbcol3">
  <!--Start Grey Box-->
  <br />
  <h3>Account Actions</h3>

  <div id="">
    <p class="squ">
      <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" id="" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <p class="squ">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" id="" />
  </p>
  <p class="squ"> <a id="" href="orderhistory.aspx">Order history</a>
  </p>
  <p class="squ"> <a id="" href="changepassword.aspx">Change password</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

As you can see from the snippet, I am using positioning and `inline-block` elements in order to achieve this kind of result.

However, the

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

doesn't seem to adhere to the line-height property.

Is this by design that the button doesn't alter its line height, even though it should be overwritten?

---

I have found that setting `background` to `transparent` seems to 'remove' this limitation - and hence my question:

working demo:

```css
.squ{
    height:30vw;
    width:40vw;
    background:gray;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
}

.jbcol3{
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
}

.squ input, .squ a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    line-height:40vw;
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="jbcol3">
    <!--Start Grey Box-->
    <br />
     <h3>Account Actions</h3>

    <div id="">
        <p class="squ">
            <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" id=""/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="squ">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" id="" />
    </p>
    <p class="squ"> <a id="" href="orderhistory.aspx">Order history</a>
    </p>
        <p class="squ"> <a id="" href="changepassword.aspx">Change password</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

It has also been noted that setting `-webkit-appearance: none;` will also remove this behaviour - so it would suggest that this is default behaviour in which you have to override other properties in order for this to be shown?

---

**Why is it that setting a background color allows the button to use this line height? why does this not work automatically?**

Comment: I see both snippets working fine in FF38.

Comment: **Note:** There's been a discusion on that topic on [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/377). However, [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#L293) adds `-webkit-appearance: button;` which seems to fix that issue. [Here's a fiddle of your first example with normalize.css included](http://jsfiddle.net/4akq2r90/).

Comment: Try isolating the submit button giving it only one css property because line-height does normally work for the input tag.  You have several other subproperties and styles associated with the button in the above code.  Once you have isolated the button and have the code working then individually add back the properties you need until you find the culprit causing the code not to work as intended

Comment: @Vucko: cheers for the link. However, it doesn't seem to explain *why* this works (As shown in my second snippet, adding a background or `-webkit-appearance` works). My question was more of *why*

Comment: Good Question! well i don't know this reason but you could you use button and line-height works there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question of *why* it happens.

But after a little and fast investigation I've came up with some results.

First, if the input has the type `submit` it gains the `-webkit-appearance: push-button`. And the `line-height` is forced to `normal`. And when I say forced it's really forced to `normal`.

In the **computed styles** you get:

```
line-height: normal;
.squ button, .squ input, .squ a - 40vw!important
input[type="submit"] - 40vw!important
input, textarea, keygen, select, button - normal user agent stylesheet
```

Even though I am overwriting it with `40vw!important` it renders as `normal`. I even tried with `40px!important`. `normal` is related to the `font-size` .. so I tried to cover that by changing the `font-size` and nothing would happen.

Now, if we remove the `-webkit-appearance: push-button` by overwriting with `none` it loses the forced `line-height: normal`.

But what happens when you change the `background-color` ? The browser by default places the `-webkit-appearance` with `none` allowing you to overwrite the `line-height`.

The `line-height` is forced by the browser in the `push-button` appearance. So, lets try this with a `button` tag instead.

```
<button type="submit">Make Payment</button>
```

What do we get?

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
line-height: 334.799987792969px;
```

**Conclusions:**

- `-webkit-appearance: push-button` makes the browser force the
  `line-height: normal`.
- `-webkit-appearance: button` allows to edit the `line-height`.
- `background-color` sets `-webkit-appearance`
  to `none`

Don't know if it's the answer you wanted but I think this results are quite interesting.

Comment: Along very similar lines as to what I was just writing. I would use a button element instead. Haven't used a input of type submit since ie6 was dropped from all the projects I work on :)

Comment: Cheers for your investigation - it is both quite an interesting read and fairly informing - although I would still like to know *why* this happens.

Comment: @jbutler483 I thinks it's default from the browser, at least I can't find anything else saying the opposite. I just posted it as an answer because I found it interesting despite not answering fully to your question. but I'll try to find more regarding this issue

Comment: @jbutler483 the `-webkit-appearance` exists to allow you to use the default UI styles. Obviously you can't overwrite some css styles of those appearances else they won't be the same as the UI .. in this case you can't overwrite the `line-height` for the `push-button`